# Form visibility in a landing page

Tags: forms, landing-page

On a landing page, is it better to make the form automatically visible once you get on the page or put a button and wait for the user to click it to make the form  visible ? what's best to get more conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase the conversion it should be visible in the first place. The fewer actions a user has to do, better conversion.

[Form length](https://www.ventureharbour.com/how-form-length-impacts-conversion-rates/) and [page speed](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/page-load-time-conversion-rates) are also important.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the content and (micro-/macro-) goals on your landing page but in most cases:

- Less clicks -> better UX.

Answer (score 0):

You should Plan the Path According to your Goal and the Product type.

But Always Remove Un-required Steps from the process to make it user-friendly.